# Can't apply Gradient Color on Text with Animation

Tags: html, css, gradient

I want to apply gradient color on `h1` with animation. I have [this](https://codepen.io/coderscoding-the-selector/pen/wvmwxjq) code on `codepen`. If i remove comment from `h1` in css then i can't see text with applied gradient, text is there but the color is not visible.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml2 .letter');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml2 .letter',
    scale: [4,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 950,
    delay: (el, i) => 70*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 100,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FDFBFB, #EBEDEE 70%);
}
.ml2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.ml2 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

/* h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #30CFD0 0%, #330867 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
} */
```

```html
  <body>  
    
          <h1 class="ml2"><span class="letter"> Hello World!</span></h1>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's getting cut off is because the background gradient does not fill the area where the text is bigger. Add padding to the element with the background gradient on.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml2 .letter');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml2 .letter',
    scale: [4,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 950,
    delay: (el, i) => 70*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 100,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FDFBFB, #EBEDEE 70%);
}
.ml2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  padding: 100px;
}

.ml2 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #30CFD0 0%, #330867 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
  <body>  
    
          <h1 class="ml2"><span class="letter"> Hello World!</span></h1>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I doesn't found it working.

Comment: I'm using firefox where it works. Seems to be a browser issue.

Comment: Yeah!! That's Working on Firefox so but what should i do for chrome and edge i have seen on both but it doesn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ml2 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: it's only apply for one text.

Comment: I want to look like this https://codepen.io/leocampos/pen/pPwwNR gradient.

Comment: Hi! I have just uncomment your H1 style its working for me.

Comment: it's not working when animation is running

Comment: Which  browser r u using?